# Accessing Current Recipient in Sitecore's Email Campaign Manager

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-ecm

I have implemented a layout and sublayouts for my Sitecore ECM implementation, it renders and emails great.  What I am struggling with now is getting the context recipient in my sublayout so I can personalize the display.  I need to evaluate relationships and other small business logic that can not be evaluated with the simple $token$ syntax.

I've been using the `Sitecore.Context.User` to no avail.  So my question is, what is the proper way to get the context user in a Sitecore ECM sublayout?

Sitecore.NET 6.5.0 (rev. 121009)
E-mail Campaign Manager 1.3.3 (rev. 130212)

Comment: I think I found the answer in the POST variables. `ec_recipient` contains the user's `domain\localname`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the current recipient during the rendering of a Sitecore ECM Newsletter by using the `ec_recipient` POST variable:

```
Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.FromName(Request["ec_recipient"]);
```

Comment: Sorry to answer my own question but I just figured it out.

Comment: It's good that you answered your own question, cos now I know too. :p Thanks.